# ActiveRecord preload error when using where() with join() and includes()

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

I want to find posts which have a specific comment and print out **all** its comments (not just that specific comment).

In order to search through an associate model, I used where() along with joins() like the following code:

```
posts = Post.joins(:comments).where('comments.value = "value1"')
```

This returns the correct post but it generates n + 1 query when I try to use the comments in the result. So I tried to use includes() to preload:

```
posts = Post.includes(:comments).joins(:comments).where('comments.value = "value1"')
```

This also returns the correct posts but when I try to call `post.comments`, it only contains **one** comment (the one with value "value1") within each post where every post should have more than one comment.

It seems like a Rails bug to me where `post.comments` should always return all the associated comments but in this case it only returns one.

My question is:

1. Is this a Rails bug or am I misunderstanding how ActiveRecord should work?
2. What is the best way to find all the posts with such comment and print all the comments of the posts without generating a n + 1 query?

Code reproduce the bug:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

begin
  require "bundler/inline"
rescue LoadError => e
  $stderr.puts "Bundler version 1.10 or later is required. Please update your Bundler"
  raise e
end

gemfile(true) do
  source "https://rubygems.org"

  git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

  # Activate the gem you are reporting the issue against.
  gem "activerecord", "5.2.0"
  gem "sqlite3"
end

require "active_record"
require "minitest/autorun"
require "logger"
require "pp"

# Ensure backward compatibility with Minitest 4
Minitest::Test = MiniTest::Unit::TestCase unless defined?(Minitest::Test)

# This connection will do for database-independent bug reports.
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(adapter: "sqlite3", database: ":memory:")
ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)

ActiveRecord::Schema.define do
  create_table :posts, force: true do |t|
  end

  create_table :comments, force: true do |t|
    t.string  :value
    t.integer :post_id
  end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end

class BugTest < Minitest::Test
  def test_association_stuff
    post = Post.create!
    post.comments << Comment.create(value: 'value1')
    post.comments << Comment.create(value: 'value2')
    post.comments << Comment.create(value: 'value3')

    post = Post.create!
    post.comments << Comment.create(value: 'value1')
    post.comments << Comment.create(value: 'value2')
    post.comments << Comment.create(value: 'value3')

    # find the post that has comment 'value1'
    posts = Post.joins(:comments).where('comments.value LIKE "%value1%"')

    posts.each { |p| pp p.comments }
    assert_equal 3, posts.first.comments.length

    # to pervent n + 1, use includes as well
    posts = Post.includes(:comments).joins(:comments).where('comments.value LIKE "%value1%"')

    posts.each { |p| pp p.comments }
    assert_equal 3, posts.first.comments.length
  end
end
```

Comment: "generates n + 1 query when I try to use the comments in the result is not clear. Also please read & act on [mcve], put code in your question not just a link to it.

Comment: I don''t know if I'm missing somehting, but you do are creating just **one** comment with the string "value1" in the gist.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. Since you are applying a WHERE clause to the comments table only rows that match the where clause will be returned by the query. Also `.joins` produces a `INNER JOIN` while `.includes` gives an `OUTER JOIN` which will give different results.

Comment: Shouldn't `post.comments` be consistent that it always returns all of the comments associated to the post? In my example, if you call `post.comments` on the first example you get all the comments but on the second example you only get one comment.

Comment: I can't follow you. Can you update your question with code describing your last comment?

Comment: Nope, thats kinda the whole point of preloading. It sets a flag on the association that is is already loaded so that calling `post.comments` does not cause a second query. ActiveRecord does not in any way guarentee that `post.comments` is equal to `Comment.where(post: post)`. If you think about it that would be pretty horrible since it means that you could not limit the number of records that are prefetched which means that your server will run out of memory given enough records.

Comment: If you edit this question with an example of the input data and desired output we might be able to give you an answer on how to actually solve the issue.

Comment: Thank all of you for responding! I've updated the question, please let me know if there is anything unclear.